# Rename elements of list based on condition

Tags: r, list, conditional-statements

I have a huge list `samplelist` containing various tibbles (in the simplified sample called `Alpha`, `Beta` and `Gamma`). Each tibble contains various elements (in the sample called `sample_0` and `sample_1`). However, not each tibble contains each element (`Gamma` contains only `sample_0`, but not `sample_1`). What I would like to do is to rename the elements based on a condition: if there is an element `sample_1` in a tibble, rename it to `sampling`. However, if the tibble does not contain `sample_1`, rename `sample_0` to `sampling` (so that the list now contains an element called `sampling` for each tibble).

```
samplelist <- list(Alpha = structure(list(sample_0 = c(3, NA, 7, 9, 2),
                                     sample_1 = c(NA, 8, 5, 4, NA)),
                                row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")),
              Beta = structure (list(sample_0 = c(2, 9, NA, 3, 7),
                                     sample_1 = c(3, 7, 9, 3, NA)),
                                row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")),
              Gamma = structure(list(sample_0 = c(NA, NA, 4, 6, 3)),
                                row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

Does anybody know how to get the following desired output?

```
samplelist
$Alpha
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  sample_0 sampling
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1        3       NA
2       NA        8
3        7        5
4        9        4
5        2       NA

$Beta
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  sample_0 sampling
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1        2        3
2        9        7
3       NA        9
4        3        3
5        7       NA

$Gamma
# A tibble: 5 x 1
       sampling
          <dbl>
  1          NA
  2          NA
  3           4
  4           6
  5           3
```

**EDIT**
With the code provided by @akrun:

```
map(errorlist,  ~  if(ncol(.x) == 1 && names(.x) == 'sample_0')
      setNames(.x, 'sampling') else 
      rename_with(.x, ~ 'sampling', matches('sample_1')))
```

I got the disired output for my samplelist. However, if there's more than one group in `Gamma`, the (adjusted) code only works for `Alpha` and `Beta`, yet leaves `Gamma` unchanged (`Delta` added from before editing):

```
errorlist <- list(Alpha = structure(list(sample_0 = c(3, NA, 7, 9, 2),
                                         sample_1 = c(NA, 8, 5, 4, NA),
                                         sample_2 = c(7, 3, 5, NA, NA)),
                                    row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                                    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")),
                  Beta = structure (list(sample_0 = c(2, 9, NA, 3, 7),
                                         sample_1 = c(3, 7, 9, 3, NA),
                                         sample_2 = c(4, 2, 6, 4, 6)),
                                    row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                                    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")),
                  Gamma = structure(list(sample_0 = c(NA, NA, 4, 6, 3),
                                         sample_1 = c(3, 7, 3, NA, 8)),
                                    row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                                    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")),
                  Delta = structure (list(error = c(3, 7, 9, 3, NA)),
                                     row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                                     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))

map(errorlist,  ~  if(ncol(.x) == 1 && names(.x) == 'sample_1')
  setNames(.x, 'sampling') else 
    rename_with(.x, ~ 'sampling', matches('sample_2')))
```

Output:

```
$Alpha
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  sample_0 sample_1 sampling
     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1        3       NA        7
2       NA        8        3
3        7        5        5
4        9        4       NA
5        2       NA       NA

$Beta
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  sample_0 sample_1 sampling
     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1        2        3        4
2        9        7        2
3       NA        9        6
4        3        3        4
5        7       NA        6

$Gamma
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  sample_0 sample_1
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1       NA        3
2       NA        7
3        4        3
4        6       NA
5        3        8

$Delta
# A tibble: 5 x 1
  error
  <dbl>
1     3
2     7
3     9
4     3
5    NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option - loop over the `list` with `map` and do the changes with a condition (`if/else`) (Here, we are using `errorlist` as it is more general.  It also works with samplelist)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map(errorlist,  ~  if(ncol(.x) == 1 && names(.x) == 'sample_0')
      setNames(.x, 'sampling') else 
      rename_with(.x, ~ 'sampling', matches('sample_1')))
```

-output

```
$Alpha
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  sample_0 sampling
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1        3       NA
2       NA        8
3        7        5
4        9        4
5        2       NA

$Beta
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  sample_0 sampling
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1        2        3
2        9        7
3       NA        9
4        3        3
5        7       NA

$Gamma
# A tibble: 5 × 1
  sampling
     <dbl>
1       NA
2       NA
3        4
4        6
5        3

$Delta
# A tibble: 5 × 1
  error
  <dbl>
1     3
2     7
3     9
4     3
5    NA
```

---

#### Update

Based on the OP's comments

```
lapply(errorlist, \(x) {
  nm1 <- stringr::str_subset(names(x), "^sample_\\d+$")
  i1 <- which.max(as.numeric(stringr::str_extract(nm1, 
       "(?<=sample_)\\d+")))
   if(length(i1) > 0) names(x)[names(x) == nm1[i1]] <- "sampling"
   x})
```

-output

```
$Alpha
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  sample_0 sample_1 sampling
     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1        3       NA        7
2       NA        8        3
3        7        5        5
4        9        4       NA
5        2       NA       NA

$Beta
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  sample_0 sample_1 sampling
     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1        2        3        4
2        9        7        2
3       NA        9        6
4        3        3        4
5        7       NA        6

$Gamma
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  sample_0 sampling
     <dbl>    <dbl>
1       NA        3
2       NA        7
3        4        3
4        6       NA
5        3        8

$Delta
# A tibble: 5 × 1
  error
  <dbl>
1     3
2     7
3     9
4     3
5    NA
```

Comment: For the example, it worked like a charm, thank you! However, if I add another element "sample_2" for Alpha and Beta and "sample_1" for Gamma (and accordingly update the statements in your loop to ... map(errorlist,  ~  if(ncol(.x) == 1 && names(.x) == 'sample_1') setNames(.x, 'sampling') else  rename_with(.x, ~ 'sampling',
 matches('sample_2'))) ..., it only changes sample_2 to sampling, yet sample_1 remains unchanged. Could this be to the statement ... if(ncol(.x) == 1 ..., which does not hold true anymore? Furthermore, could you explain why you used setNames first, and then rename_with?

Comment: @Gnueghoidune because there was only a single column and it was much more easier to use `setNames` .  Your comment about the new issue is not clear to me

Comment: Edited the question to clarify the new issue

Comment: @Gnueghoidune try the update

Comment: After having changed the backslash in the first row to function, it worked impeccably! You are a real hero!

Comment: @Gnueghoidune i think that may be because your R version is old.  It is a shortcut for lambda function (`function(x)`)